# Django - overridden save function won't save parent fields

Tags: django

I'm creating a django app for an education company, and I created a custom user model and two classes (Student and Teacher) that will inherit from the User model through a one-to-one relationship.

I'm trying to avoid the situation where a teacher and a student both use the same user object. Thus, I have a user_type char field in my User object, and the idea is when a user is set to a teacher, the field will be updated. Then if I try to make the user a student, it should throw an error.

I'm trying to do the check in the clean function - after the clean() function is called in the save() function, the user_type seems to be updated, but when I actually test, it seems user_type is returning a blank string. I'm wondering if someone could point me the right direction.

```
class User(AbstractUser):    
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=USER_TYPES, blank=True)

class Teacher(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def clean(self):
        if self.user.user_type and self.user.user_type !='teacher':
            raise ValidationError('Some error')
        else:
            self.user.user_type = 'teacher'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.clean()
        #this prints 'teacher'
        print(self.user.user_type)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

tests.py
#this test fails
def test_should_set_user_type_automatically_to_teacher(self):
    user = User.objects.create(username='tangbj', first_name='Dan')
    Teacher.objects.create(user=user)        
    teacher = Teacher.objects.get(user__username='tangbj')

    print(teacher.user.user_type)
    self.assertEqual(teacher.user.user_type, 'teacher')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving the `Teacher` instance, **not** the `User` instance. When you assign the `user_type`, you should do a `save(..)` to the `User` instance. Records aren't magically updated.

Said in another way; you are modifying an instance attribute, but you are not saving the instance.

Comment: Thank you! So super.save() doesn't actually save the parent. Doesn't super refer to the parent? And this is different from self.user.save()?Sorry, very new to django

Comment: Is not a problem of Django knowledge; the fact is that your parent class is not `User`. Your parent class is a model called `TimeStampedModel`, and its `save` is the one who is called. `user` attribute has nothing to do with it. You should review what [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) is used for.

Comment: Oh dang, you are right - I forgot that user was an attribute and not the parent class. Thanks for pointing that out.